# Load customer address by ID, Magento

Tags: magento

Is there a way to load a customer's address by ID?

Like the way customer loading by username does:

```
 $customer->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
```

I need it because I'm trying to know if the address already exists so I can decide to create a new one or to update the existing one

Comment: Which address and in what context?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that the 'ID' is referring to the address id (and not the customer id) then

```
$id = 5;
Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($id);
```

(it always wise to do security check when loading by id)

See deleteAction() in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php

Answer (score 22):

I use this, because they can set more than one address in Mage ...

```php
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->load($customer_id); // insert customer ID

foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address)
{
    $data = $address->toArray();
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Of course the `var_dump` will display all the array data .. it's up to you to manipulate and pull out the address you're looking for at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#customer id here
$customerId = 1;
#load customer object
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);     //insert     cust ID
  #create customer address array
  $customerAddress = array();
#loop to create the array
foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address)
{
   $customerAddress[] = $address->toArray();
}
#displaying the array
echo '<pre/>';print_r($customerAddress );exit;
```